# Power BI DAX - how to calculate % conversion from Trial to Full licence

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Please could someone help me with this? I've been trying for days and can't make it work.

I want measures which calculate what % of all 'Trial' sales get converted to 'Full' sales. I'd like this dynamic by product, date, and various other variables not included in this dummy data eg customer segment.

Dummy data follows:
[image]

Comment: Please explain and show what result you expect so we can help you.. I mean you can put it in a matrix visual and it does the job for you but telling us what the end result should look like will help.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying. Does this help?

In the above sample:

Andy takes out a trial for Bike and Car, and Car is converted to Full, not bike
Brenda takes out a trial for Bike and Car, converts neither to Full
Carol same as Brenda
Darren takes out a trial for Bike and Car, converts both to Full

So for Bike - 1 out of 4 customers converts to Full, so conversion rate is 25%
for Car - 2 out of 4 customers convert to Full, so conversion rate is 50%

There is more nuance in next message...

Comment: I'd like measures which give:
Number of unique customers which take out a Trial (by product)
Number of the above which also convert their Trial to a Full licence

In reality there are a lot more sale types so really I want 'Trial and <>Trial

And I also care about dates - I want Full which comes after the latest Trial. There will likely be some to-ing and fro-ing where some customers took Full years ago and subsequent Trials, they need to be excluded.

Comment: So there is logic and dependancy on earlier lines. Andy got himself the full license so we should not calculate his trial anymore. Also you do not care if he had many trials before..

Comment: Yes - exactly. I want number of customers who took a Trial where MAX(Trial date) <= MIN (Non-Trial date)

I can define all the measures and they look OK but when I try and put the final one in, it always returns BLANK, no idea why. From eyeballling a data table I can see data lines which meet my criteria

Comment: Apologies for my lack of formatting btw, I tried <br/> and it didn't seem to work?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I addad an extra column what shows a trail which are converted to (one or more) full. So if the column stays empty, no full lic. Others get converted. You can make a true/false out of this column if needed but this should allow to make the stats you are looking for. The number behind the full tells the customer got more licenses after..

```
Converted = 
var prod = Lic[Product]
var cust = Lic[Customer]
var trialDate = Lic[Purchase OD]
return CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Lic), FILTER(Lic, prod = Lic[Product] && trialDate <= Lic[Purchase OD] && Lic[Sales type] = "Full" && cust = Lic[Customer]))
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Sorry for slow reply - I ended up working something like this out myself but nowhere near as elegantly, so I've used your DAX instead. Cheers!